# How to copy all conversation from iMessages to Mac without using Apple ID? Any app to do that?

Tags: iphone, mac, messages, apple-id

So I have a long conversation on my iPhone in the iMessages app. It is a long text message conversation with a friend. Now I want a copy of the whole conversation so I can send to another friend.

Right now I do: take a screen shot of every block of the conversation and send to my friend ⇒ 20 screenshots. Not practical for me and my recipient.

I know you can have iMessages in your MAC by using your Apple ID but I don't want to use my Apple ID with iMessages. I want to continue to use my phone number. If I change to Apple ID people will see my Apple ID when I send a message to them using my phone. And I don't want to share this private information.

So is there some app that will allow me to just copy the whole conversation of my iMessage app to someplace else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are apps such as [BackupTrans](http://www.backuptrans.com/iphone-sms-mms-imessage-transfer.html), which will copy all messages from an iPhone to a Mac.  I have used that one with some success.  There are several others in the same price range.